# Does anyone know how to process a collection one by one using two threads?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, multithreading, producer-consumer

I want to dequeue the elements of a collection one by one then store their values in a MYSQL database.

When the first element is dequeued I want to start a thread to update the database, then when the second element is dequeued I want to start another thread.

When the first thread finishes execution, I want to reuse it handle the third element of in the queue.  Then, after the second thread finishes execution, I want to reuse it to handle the fourth element in the queue.  I want to continue this way until all the elements in the queue are processed.

These all process handle the another thread at 1ms.

Does anyone know how to process a collection one by one using two threads?

Comment: ??????????????? no idea what you are talking about, what have you tried so far, do you have pseudo code, post tables. To me this question looks unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: Might want to look into the `Thread Pool` class:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx . Also maybe explain a bit more which part exactly it is you're having trouble with.

Comment: What is the question?  What code have you written?

Answer (score 2):

It seems complicated and unnecessary to solve this problem in the exact manner you suggested.  Essentially you have mapped out system where one thread handles all the items in the collection with even numbered indexes, and the other handles all the items with odd numbered indexes.

However, if your real goal is to process a queue using two threads, and it doesn't matter which thread processes which item, here is one way to do that using the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` class:

```
    // Queue of items to process
    static ConcurrentQueue<string> queue;

    // Random number generator to simulate time it takes to do work.
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Items to process.
        List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Joe", "Bob", "Fred", "Jack", "Jill", 
            "Suzy", "Amy", "Alice", "Andy", "Bill", "Chuck" };

        // Demonstrates putting the items into a concurrent queue.
        queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(names);

        // Work threads
        Thread first = new Thread(AddToDatabase);
        Thread second = new Thread(AddToDatabase);

        // Start the work threads
        first.Start("First");
        second.Start("Second");
    }

    // Simulated work routine.
    static void AddToDatabase(object state)
    {
        string name;
        while (queue.TryDequeue(out name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(state, ": Putting ", name, " in the database."));
            Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1000, 5000));
        }
    }
```

Running this code produces output like this:

```
First: Putting Joe in the database.
Second: Putting Bob in the database.
Second: Putting Fred in the database.
First: Putting Jack in the database.
Second: Putting Jill in the database.
First: Putting Suzy in the database.
Second: Putting Amy in the database.
First: Putting Alice in the database.
Second: Putting Andy in the database.
First: Putting Bill in the database.
Second: Putting Chuck in the database.
```

As you can see both threads are working their way through the queue, generally switching back and fourth, but nothing guarantees they will execute in any particular order.

However, even this code is more work than you really need to do.  You can use parallel LINQ and let the framework decide how many threads you need:

```
// Items to process.
List<string> names = new List<string>() { 
    "Joe", "Bob", "Fred", "Jack", "Jill", "Suzy", "Amy", "Alice", 
    "Andy", "Bill", "Chuck" };

// Process using Parallel LINQ
names.AsParallel().ForAll(name =>
{
    var id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(id, ": Putting ", name, " in the database."));
    Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1000, 5000));
});
```

Which produces similar output:

```
1: Putting Amy in the database.
3: Putting Joe in the database.
1: Putting Alice in the database.
1: Putting Andy in the database.
3: Putting Bob in the database.
3: Putting Fred in the database.
1: Putting Bill in the database.
3: Putting Jack in the database.
1: Putting Chuck in the database.
3: Putting Jill in the database.
3: Putting Suzy in the database.
```

I've left out the parts of the code that would actually put the items in a database.  That is really a separate question from how to process your collection using more than one thread.  If you would like information about how classes like `ConcurrentQueue<T>` work, check out Jon Skeet's [article on multi-threading in .NET.](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/deadlocks.shtml)

Comment: +1 this is very thorough but you do still have to watch out for [false sharing](http://drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/217500206?pgno=1) due to the potential of sharing cache lines on the collection, which result in sequential like performance

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Thanks for the interesting link.